# sqlalchemy MSSQL Cannot insert/update datetime2

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I need to bulk insert & update data in MSSQL using sqlalchemy 2.0, it's working but is always ignoring my two datetime fields without error, I end up with NULL in those fields

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, ForeignKey, String, insert, update
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import DATETIME2
from dateutil import parser

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class issues(Base):
    __tablename__ = "issues"
    id = mapped_column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    created = mapped_column (DATETIME2())
    updated = mapped_column (DATETIME2())
    status = mapped_column(String(50))
    severity = mapped_column(String(10))
    control_id = mapped_column(String(36))
    entity_id = mapped_column(String(36))
```

I've tried creating my dict as a date object and a string neither works and MSSQL accepts the data if I insert it manually:

```
issueList.append({
    'id': issue['id'],
    # 'createdAt': parser.parse(issue['createdAt']).__str__(),
    'createdAt': parser.parse(issue['createdAt']),
    # 'updatedAt': parser.parse(issue['updatedAt']).__str__(),
    'updatedAt': parser.parse(issue['updatedAt']),
    'status': issue['status'],
    'severity': issue['severity'],
    'control_id': issue['control']['id'],
    'entity_id': issue['entity']['id']
})


session.execute(insert(issues),issueList)
session.execute(update(issues),issueListUpdates) 
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooops I found the issue when creating the dictionary I used “createdAt” and “updatedAt” (this matches the api I’m reading) but the model doesn’t include the At. When I correct this the data inserted correctly.

One thing that help debug this was adding `echo=True` to the engine definition this printed out the SQL in which I could see those fields where missed out.